# How to validate JWT from Azure AD B2C in ASP.NET Core 2.1 API after Ocelot API-Gateway

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.1, ocelot

I use Ocelot as a API-Gateway for our micro-services which are build using ASP.NET Core 2.1.

Ocelot is authenticating the bearer token from AD B2C and calling my web API.

I configured my web service with the standard Azure AD B2Z authentication code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme) .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
```

The API always returns 401 ("The issuer is invalid"). The error might come from the fact that Ocelot is in the middle.

I think I would not need a full authentication but rather a JWT token validation. However, I cannot find any sample code that works with JWT and ASP.NET core 2.1, especially with Ocelot as a middleman. I probably have to skip issuer verification but I don't know how to add a TokenValidationParameters object to the configuration.

Has anybody build such a system? How do you handle / validate the tokens coming from the gateway?

Comment: Ocelot just calls the asp.net authentication code, so I don't think the "issuer is invalid" error is related.

Comment: Ocelet calls context.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(context.DownstreamReRoute.AuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationProviderKey);